# Nginx auth_request_set directive doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I have a sample config:

```
    upstream content {
      server 127.0.0.1:4001;
    }

    server {
        listen 4000;

        location /test-auth {
            add_header X-Test "test value";
            return 200;
        }

        location /proxy {
            add_header "X-Test1" "test1";
            auth_request /test-auth;
            auth_request_set $test $upstream_http_x_test;
            auth_request_set $test2 $upstream_status;
            proxy_pass http://content?test=$test&test2=$test2;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;
            add_header X-Test $test;
            add_header X-Test2 $test2;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 4001;
        add_header X-Test3 "test3";
        return 200 "test response $args";
    }
```

I want to pass the `X-Test` header from the auth location to the browser when requesting `/proxy`. This should be done by the `auth_request_set` directive by pulling the `$upstream_http_x_test` variable value. But it's always empty while the header is set in the auth endpoint output. When accessing the `/test-auth` directly, it's present in the output. But I can't get it' in the `/proxy` location. Moreover, the `$upstream_status` should be always present showing the auth request status, but it's also empty. When I do a request to `/proxy`, I'm getting only these:

```
X-Test3: test3
X-Test1: test1

test response test=&test2=
```

But I also need to have `X-Test` and `X-Test2` headers filled by the data from the auth request and corresponding values in the content part.

The `/test-auth` endpoint is called correctly. If I return 401 in it, requests to `/proxy` are failing with 401 too.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`auth_request_set` variables are not accessible inside `location` blocks, but are available inside `access_by_lua`, try this:

```
  access_by_lua_block {
    ngx.header["X-Test2"] = ngx.var["test2"]
  }
```